# How to remove this plastic pipe connector?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

How do I remove this kind of white plastic connector attached to the metal pipe?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On the other side of the cube at the top of the white part is a clip that fits inside the cube. Pull that out and the white part will come off the brass part.

Comment: It looks exactly the same on the other side of the cube.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a manufacturer's equipment specific fitting. Disconnect both supply lines at the supply valves, then unscrew the fitting.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Leave the sleeve on. There's an arrow on it pointing up indicating that you need to push up on the fitting first. This will loosen the locking clip inside. You then squeeze on the sleeve while still pushing up for the clip to release which will let you remove the whole assembly. I just learned this replacing the faucet in my restroom.

Answer (score 0):

Take sleve off, push tabs on either side of cube and pull

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).